# Certified Document when Approval Signature exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, certificate, pdfbox

Working with java use Apache PDFBox to sign and certified, invalid certified if signature exist, with JsignPDF was able to certified when approval exist, the process is sign after that do certified (seal) document

Signature with JsignPDF

[image: Document with approval sign]

document after certified with JsignPDF :

[image: Document signed with certified]

the certified invalid with PDFBox

[image: Invalid certified PDFBox]

the function from PDFBox with some editing was to try :

```
public void signPDF(File inputFile, File signedFile,  Rectangle2D humanRect, String tsaUrl, int page, String SignatureField, boolean isWithQR, String name, UserSignature userSignature) throws IOException, CertificateEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, OperatorCreationException, CMSException {
        if (inputFile == null || !inputFile.exists()) {
            throw new IOException("Document for signing does not exist");
        }

        setTsaUrl(tsaUrl);
        // creating output document and prepare the IO streams.

//        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(signedFile);
//             PDDocument doc = Loader.loadPDF(inputFile)) {

        // creating output document and prepare the IO streams.
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(signedFile);

        // load document
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(inputFile);

            int accessPermissions = SigUtils.getMDPPermission(doc);
            LogSystem.info("Document permission " + accessPermissions);
            if (accessPermissions == 1) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("No changes to the document are permitted due to DocMDP transform parameters dictionary");
            }
            // Note that PDFBox has a bug that visual signing on certified files with permission 2
            // doesn't work properly, see PDFBOX-3699. As long as this issue is open, you may want to
            // be careful with such files.

            PDSignature signature = null;
            PDAcroForm acroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm(null);
            PDRectangle rect = null;

            // sign a PDF with an existing empty signature, as created by the CreateEmptySignatureForm example.
            if (acroForm != null) {
                signature = findExistingSignature(acroForm, SignatureField);
                if (signature != null) {
                    rect = acroForm.getField(SignatureField).getWidgets().get(0).getRectangle();
                }
            }

            if (signature == null) {
                // create signature dictionary
                signature = new PDSignature();
            }


            if (rect == null) {
                rect = createSignatureRectangle(doc, humanRect);
            }

            // Optional: certify
            // can be done only if version is at least 1.5 and if not already set
            // doing this on a PDF/A-1b file fails validation by Adobe preflight (PDFBOX-3821)
            // PDF/A-1b requires PDF version 1.4 max, so don't increase the version on such files.

//            if (doc.getVersion() >= 1.5f && accessPermissions == 0)
//            {
//                SigUtils.setMDPPermission(doc, signature, 2);
//            }

            if (acroForm != null && acroForm.getNeedAppearances()) {
                // PDFBOX-3738 NeedAppearances true results in visible signature becoming invisible
                // with Adobe Reader
                if (acroForm.getFields().isEmpty()) {
                    // we can safely delete it if there are no fields
                    acroForm.getCOSObject().removeItem(COSName.NEED_APPEARANCES);
                    // note that if you've set MDP permissions, the removal of this item
                    // may result in Adobe Reader claiming that the document has been changed.
                    // and/or that field content won't be displayed properly.
                    // ==> decide what you prefer and adjust your code accordingly.
                } else {
                    System.out.println("/NeedAppearances is set, signature may be ignored by Adobe Reader");
                }
            }

            // default filter
            signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);

            // subfilter for basic and PAdES Part 2 signatures
            signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);

            signature.setName("Name");
            signature.setLocation("Location");
            
            if(userSignature.getType().equals("sign"))
            {
                signature.setReason("Reason");
                if (accessPermissions == 0) {

                    COSDictionary sigDict = signature.getCOSObject();

                    // DocMDP specific stuff
                    COSDictionary transformParameters = new COSDictionary();
                    transformParameters.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.TRANSFORM_PARAMS);
                    transformParameters.setInt(COSName.P, 0);
                    transformParameters.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);

                    COSDictionary referenceDict = new COSDictionary();
                    referenceDict.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.SIG_REF);
                    referenceDict.setItem(COSName.TRANSFORM_METHOD, COSName.DOCMDP);
                    referenceDict.setItem(COSName.DIGEST_METHOD, COSName.getPDFName("SHA256"));
                    referenceDict.setItem(COSName.TRANSFORM_PARAMS, transformParameters);
                    referenceDict.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);

                    COSArray referenceArray = new COSArray();
                    referenceArray.add(referenceDict);
                    sigDict.setItem(COSName.REFERENCE, referenceArray);
                    referenceArray.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);

                    COSDictionary catalogDict = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject();
                    COSDictionary permsDict = new COSDictionary();
                    catalogDict.setItem(COSName.PERMS, permsDict);
                    permsDict.setItem(COSName.DOCMDP, signature);
                    catalogDict.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
                    permsDict.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
                }
            }
            if(userSignature.getType().equals("seal"))
            {
                signature.setReason(userSignature.getQrText());
//                try {
//                    if (doc.getVersion() >= 1.5f && accessPermissions == 0)
//                    {
//                        SigUtils.setMDPPermission(doc, signature, 2);
//                    }
//                }catch(Exception e)
//                {
//                    e.printStackTrace();
//                }
                if (accessPermissions == 0) {
                    //            SigUtils.setMDPPermission(document, signature, 1);
                    COSDictionary sigDict = signature.getCOSObject();

                    // DocMDP specific stuff
                    COSDictionary transformParameters = new COSDictionary();
                    transformParameters.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.TRANSFORM_PARAMS);
                    transformParameters.setInt(COSName.P, 2);
                    transformParameters.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);

                    COSDictionary referenceDict = new COSDictionary();
                    referenceDict.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.SIG_REF);
                    referenceDict.setItem(COSName.TRANSFORM_METHOD, COSName.DOCMDP);
                    referenceDict.setItem(COSName.DIGEST_METHOD, COSName.getPDFName("SHA256"));
                    referenceDict.setItem(COSName.TRANSFORM_PARAMS, transformParameters);
                    referenceDict.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);

                    COSArray referenceArray = new COSArray();
                    referenceArray.add(referenceDict);
                    sigDict.setItem(COSName.REFERENCE, referenceArray);
                    referenceArray.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);

                    COSDictionary catalogDict = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject();
                    COSDictionary permsDict = new COSDictionary();
                    catalogDict.setItem(COSName.PERMS, permsDict);
                    permsDict.setItem(COSName.DOCMDP, signature);
                    catalogDict.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
                    permsDict.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
                }
            }

            // the signing date, needed for valid signature
            signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());

            // do not set SignatureInterface instance, if external signing used
            SignatureInterface signatureInterface = isExternalSigning() ? null : this;

            // register signature dictionary and sign interface
            signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();

            signatureOptions.setVisualSignature(createVisualSignatureTemplate(doc, 0, rect, signature, isWithQR, name, userSignature.getDescOnly(), userSignature.getType(), userSignature.isVisible()));
            signatureOptions.setPage(page);



            doc.addSignature(signature, signatureInterface, signatureOptions);
            doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getField("Signature1").setPartialName(SignatureField);

            if (isExternalSigning()) {
                this.tsaUrl=tsaUrl;
//                ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning = doc.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(fos);
//                // invoke external signature service
//                byte[] cmsSignature = sign(externalSigning.getContent());



                ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning = doc.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(fos);

                // invoke external signature service
                byte[] cmsSignature =IOUtils.toByteArray(externalSigning.getContent());
                String sgn= signingProcess(cmsSignature);

                // set signature bytes received from the service
                externalSigning.setSignature(attachSignature(sgn));

            } else {
                // write incremental (only for signing purpose)
                doc.saveIncremental(fos);
            }
        doc.close();
//        } catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        } catch (OperatorCreationException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        } catch (CMSException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }

        // Do not close signatureOptions before saving, because some COSStream objects within
        // are transferred to the signed document.
        // Do not allow signatureOptions get out of scope before saving, because then the COSDocument
        // in signature options might by closed by gc, which would close COSStream objects prematurely.
        // See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3743
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(signatureOptions);
    }
```

set setMDPermission to certified the document :

```
if (accessPermissions == 0) {

    COSDictionary sigDict = signature.getCOSObject();
    
    // DocMDP specific stuff
    COSDictionary transformParameters = new COSDictionary();
    transformParameters.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.TRANSFORM_PARAMS);
    transformParameters.setInt(COSName.P, 1);
    transformParameters.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
    
    COSDictionary referenceDict = new COSDictionary();
    referenceDict.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.SIG_REF);
    referenceDict.setItem(COSName.TRANSFORM_METHOD, COSName.DOCMDP);
    referenceDict.setItem(COSName.DIGEST_METHOD, COSName.getPDFName("SHA256"));
    referenceDict.setItem(COSName.TRANSFORM_PARAMS, transformParameters);
    referenceDict.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
    
    COSArray referenceArray = new COSArray();
    referenceArray.add(referenceDict);
    sigDict.setItem(COSName.REFERENCE, referenceArray);
    referenceArray.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
    
    COSDictionary catalogDict = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject();
    COSDictionary permsDict = new COSDictionary();
    catalogDict.setItem(COSName.PERMS, permsDict);
    permsDict.setItem(COSName.DOCMDP, signature);
    catalogDict.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
    permsDict.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
}
```

Signature with the parameter "sign" and Certified with parameter "seal"

*Update, on PDFBox the first existing signature always be certified, not second signature ? can the last sign be certified and swap the first one ?

any suggest ?

Comment: First of all, if a document has a certification signature, no approval signature may come before it. You claim JsignPDF can do otherwise but according to the specification that is impossible. Thus, either JsignPDF does something entirely different than you think it does or there is a bug in Adobe Acrobat which you appear to use as validator. To verify please share example docs (before and after certifying) with previous approval signatures and then a certification signature created by JsignPDF for analysis.

Comment: However, the first signature is always be certified or can be set ?

Comment: If there is a certification signature, it must be before all approval signatures. And if there is no signature in a document yet, you can add a certification signature. And no, you cannot swap signatures.

Comment: oke, i undestand. More question if the certification signature come first then next is approval like 3 signature approval, can the last the certification setMDPPermission with 1 ? so at the end the document can't add more approval signature

Comment: *"More question if the certification signature come first then next is approval like 3 signature approval, can the last the certification setMDPPermission with 1 ?"* - You cannot use `setMDPPermission` for that as that would create another certification signature. What you can do, though, is adding a signature lock dictionary to the final signature field to sign with a **P** value of 1 to lock the document. Beware, though: This is a feature for PDF 2.0 conform viewers. Thus, Adobe Acrobat will respect that entry but some PDF viewers probably will not.

Comment: By the way, *'Signature with the parameter "sign" and Certified with parameter "seal"'* - even with the parameter "sign" your code adds a **DocMDP** transform to the signature in case of `accessPermissions == 0`; but such a **DocMDP** transform makes a signature a certification. So this obviously is wrong.

Comment: yes, i have deleted that code. now just "seal" have DocMDP transform

Comment: signature lock dictionary is show the signature pict ? i try it just show the rectangle box

Comment: *"signature lock dictionary is show the signature pict ?"* - The signature lock dictionary has nothing to do with some signature picture. Simply add a dictionary filled as described  in section 12.7.5.5 "Signature fields" of ISO 32000-2:2020 to the signature field dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer essentially is a more detailed version of the comments, essentially finding that what you want to do is not possible.*

You ask for a way to

> Certify Document when Approval Signature exist

According to the current PDF specification:

| ISO 32000-2:2020 subsection 12.8.1 "General" of 12.8 "Digital signatures" |
| --- |
| A PDF document may contain the following standard types of signatures: [...] One or more approval signatures (also known as recipient signatures). These shall follow the certification signature if one is present. |

Thus, you cannot validly add a certification signature to a PDF which already has approval signatures.

(This does not automatically mean that all validators will detect the issue if you add a certification signature after approval signatures, let alone correctly display the cause. Many validators only do a subset of the checks that strictly speaking are necessary...)

> More question if the certification signature come first then next is approval like 3 signature approval, can the last the certification setMDPPermission with 1 ? so at the end the document can't add more approval signature

`setMDPPermission` adds a **DocMDP** transform to the signature, and such a transform makes the signature a certification signature. Thus, using this method when signing a document that already has an approval signature, will create an invalid PDF or fail entirely.

You can lock a PDF document with an approval signature, though, if you add a **Lock** dictionary to the signature field with a **P** entry of 1. Beware, though, this is a ISO 32000-2 feature originally introduced as a feature of an Adobe Extension to ISO 32000-1. Not all PDF viewers support ISO 32000-2 yet, so some viewers may not respect this entry.